# Как спарсить теги без определённых атрибутов с помощью BeautifulSoup?

Tags: html, python, beautiful-soup

Помогите, пожалуйста, составить код, который будет парсить значения тегов без определённых атрибутов. Пример кода HTML:

```html
<ul id="offerpagelist_geo" class=" offer_page__list_param offer_page__list_param_geo">
<li>
  <span>Армения</span>
  <span>46 690.00 AMD</span>                                    
</li>
<li>
  <span>Азербайджан</span>
  <span>189.00 AZN</span>                                    
</li>
<li>
  <span>Беларусь</span>
  <span>164.00 BYR</span>                                    
</li>
<li>
  <span>Кыргызстан</span>
  <span>8 990.00 KGS</span>                                    
</li>
<li>
  <span>Казахстан</span>
  <span>39 990.00 KZT</span>                                    
</li>
<li>
  <span>Россия</span>
  <span>4 990.00 RUB</span>                                    
</li>
```

Нужно вытащить отсюда названия стран (Армения, Азербайджан и т.д.) и цены. У меня даже нет идей, как это можно реализовать. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> ul = soup.find(id="offerpagelist_geo")
>>> {li.span.string: li.span.find_next('span').string for li in ul.find_all('li')}
{'Армения': '46 690.00 AMD', 'Азербайджан': '189.00 AZN', 'Беларусь': '164.00 BYR', 'Кыргызстан': '8 990.00 KGS', 'Казахстан': '39 990.00 KZT', 'Россия': '4 990.00 RUB'}
```

Comment: @hohokibeza: [код однозначно рабочий](https://repl.it/@zed1/beautifulsoup-parse-ul-spans)